# Statistical Metric for Dominance of the Largest Subset in a Partition of a Set

Tags: statistics, elementary-set-theory, set-partition

Given a set and a partition of it, I want to calculate a score (between 0 and 1) reflecting **how much is the set "dominated" by the largest subset of the partition**.
The intuitive idea I'm trying to capture is, considering a set of answers to a question, what's the probability that the most common answer is correct. It might take into account the ratio between the size of the largest subset and the size of the entire set, the ratio between the largest subset to other subsets, etc.

Examples: (The numbers refer to the size of each subset in the partition)

- The score of `60,40` should be lower than `80,20` because the largest subset is smaller in comparison to the entire set.
- The score of `70,30` should be lower than `70,5,5,5,5,5,5` because there's a second subset that challenges the dominance of the largest subset.
- The score of `90,5,5` should be lower than `90,5,1,1,1,1,1` because an answer given by 5 persons challenges the dominance of the most common answer more than 5 different answers given by 5 different persons.

The closest metric I've found in search is the Gini Coefficient, but it doesn't refer specifically to the (one) largest subset, but to the general inequality between the subsets.

Is there a known metric that captures the idea I've described?

Comment: It is not clear why $70,30$ should be lower (or indeed higher) than $70,5,5,5,5,5,5$ if the criterion is "the probability that the most common answer is correct".  What would you do comparing $70,30$ and $65,5,5,5,5,5,5,5$?

Comment: @Henry 70,30 is lower than 70,5,5,5,5,5,5 because in the first case there is a second answer (30) that was given by a not negligible group of people, so I would say that it is possible that this is the correct answer and the largest set (70) is just a common mistake. In the second case, only the largest set seems reasonable, because there is no alternative answer which was selected by a not negligible group of people.